# Site URL for embedded video no longer available in Insight Data given by Youtube API v2

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am using YouTube API v2.0 for Retrieving Insight Data for a youtube video. Here is a snapshot of csv file for the video that I downloaded from youtube in January 2013 :

[image]

If we see the highlighted Source type column (which says NO_LINK_EMBEDDED), there is also the url of the website in the detail column (which says tralib.net). That means the video was embedded on tralib.net. Now, there seems to be some change in the insight data provided by youtube, due to which the site url on which video is embedded is no more available. Here is the snapshot of data for the same video taken few days back :

[image]

You can see the detail column is empty in the highlighted area. I tested csv files for many videos but in every file, detail field is empty where source type is NO_LINK_EMBEDDED. However the youtube api v2 documentation at https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_insight still claims that the url of the site should be available. Here is the text from their documentation :

> NO_LINK_EMBEDDED – The video was embedded on another website when it
>   was viewed. The Detail field in the row will identify the web page
>   where the video was embedded.

I was wondering if there is some alternate way of getting the data in old format so that I can see the site urls where my video is embedded. This information is very important for me. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce the problem with other video? If it would be a localized problem, maybe it could be a loss of data due to a hardware failure inside the youtube infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Daniel. Yes, the same problem exists with all the videos.

Comment: This was a bug tracked at https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4877 and since resolved.